# Помогите перевести код из Pascal в Python, пожалуйста

Tags: python, pascal

```
x := 0; y := 0;
for i := 1 to N do
  if a[i]>=4 then
  begin
    x := x+a[i]; //сумма
    y := y+1; //количество
  end;
s := x/y; //среднее
writeln('Sred.Ball= ',s);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = 0
y = 0

for i in range(1, N + 1):
    if a[i] >= 4:
        x = x + a[i]       # сумма
        y = y + 1          # количество

s = x / y                  # среднее
print('Sred.Ball= ',s);
```

В Питоне вместо пары `begin` / `end` используются **отступы** (обычно в форме 4 пробелов для одного уровня), значит, они важные.

Comment: Последние два оператора должны находиться на внешнем уровне. Пересмотрите, пожалуйста, код

Comment: @Евгений, по логике может быть, но в коде Pascal из вопроса этого не было (Pascal игнорирует отступы). Вопрос был только о переводе на Питон, что я сделал.

Comment: как раз в паскале последние два оператора находятся на внешнем уровне вложенности. Т.к. внутри цикла `while` находится простой оператор `if`, а не сложный оператор `begin`, последние два действия не включаются в цикл

Comment: @Евгений, 1. нет цикла `while`, 2. вы правы, я исправил мой ответ. Спасибо вам.

Comment: не `while`, а `for`. Но всё же =) А что касательно уровней - тут уже, скорее, проблема в изначальном отсутствии табуляций в исходной программе, которая была нечитаема